# To remove consecutive lines matching a pattern and the next 3 lines following it

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file with the following content:

```
dn : Does not matter
 uid=321 456 678
foo=/234
bar=/456
git=/543

 uid=321 456 678
 uid=678 987 098
foo=/234
bar=/456
git=/543

dn : Does it matter
 uid=321 456 678
foo=/543
bar=/423
git=/501
```

I want to remove any occurrences of `uid=` that occurs consecutively and also the 3 lines following it so that the expected output is:

```
 dn : Does not matter
 uid=321 456 678
foo=/234
bar=/456
git=/543

dn : Does it matter
 uid=321 456 678
foo=/543
bar=/423
git=/501
```

I have tried that on two servers. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the one server where I had tried the bulk of my attempts. So from the second server I have tried variations of the following but desired results are eluding me.

```
sed '/^ uid=/N;{/\n uid= & & \n ^change type & & \n ^replace/d;}' pattern2.txt
awk '{/pat/?f++:f=0} f==2 {f--;}; 1' < pattern2.txt
sed '/^ uid=/N;{/\n uid=/D;}' pattern1.txt
awk '{/ uid=/?f++:f=0} f==2' pattern1.txt
```

Comment: i had posted the pattern in new lines. However, this seems to be garbled up on posting

Comment: I've formatted it to preserve newlines.. in future, check https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help for help(in short, select the lines and use `ctrl+k` or press the `{}` editing icon)

Comment: also, does your input always have empty line separating the blocks containing `uid=`? if so, using awk's paragraph mode is the easiest way to solve this

Comment: yes, it invariably has the empty line separating the blocks 2 consecutive " uid="

Comment: can you check if `awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/uid=.*uid=/'` solves your problem? this works for given sample but might not work for your real use case

Comment: You are correct !!! This does not work on the real use text file. However, it work aptly on sample code.

Comment: how about this one? `awk '/uid=/ && p~/uid=/{c=4; next} !(c && c--) && NR>1{print p}; {p=$0} END{print p}'`

Comment: Thanks a ton !!!! This one works perfectly. Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed -f script.sed file
dn : Does not matter
 uid=321 456 678
foo=/234
bar=/456
git=/543

dn : Does it matter
 uid=321 456 678
foo=/543
bar=/423
git=/501
```

... where `script.sed` is

```
H              # Append a newline and the current line to the hold space
/^$/bout       # Empty line: branch to ':out'
$bout          # Last line: branch to ':out'
d              # Delete line, start again from the top
:out
x              # Swap in the data from the hold space
/uid.*uid/d    # Delete the data if it contains two "uid"
s/\n//         # Remove the first embedded newline
               # (implicit print)
```

This collects the read lines in the "hold space" (a general purpose buffer in `sed`) and when it hits an empty line or the end of input, the hold space contains one of the "blocks" in the original file.  If such a block contains two instances of the string `uid`, it is discarded, otherwise it is outputted.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` - I feel this could be simplified, but not able to so far

```
awk '/uid=/ && p~/uid=/{c=4; next}
     !(c && c--) && NR>1{print p} {p=$0}
     END{if(c==0)print p}' ip.txt
```

- by default, uninitialized variables in awk will be empty string or 0 depending on context
- `/uid=/ && p~/uid=/` if current and previous line contains `uid=`

  - `c=4; next` initialize `c` with number of lines to skip(plus 1 because of logic I ended up with). Also, skip rest of the code
- `!(c && c--) && NR>1{print p}` print previous line if current line number is greater than 1 and if `c==0`. If `c` is greater than `0`, it will continue decrementing until `c==0`
- `{p=$0}` save previous line for further use
- `END{if(c==0)print p}` print the last line if `c==0`